# Algebraic proof for the following identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Give an algebraic proof that $\binom{n+1}{m+1} = \sum_{k=m}^{n} \binom{k}{m}$.

I've tried using Pascal's rule and looking for a telescopic sum, but I can't find one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried using Pascal's rule and looking for a telescopic sum,

How about

$$\binom{k}{m} + \binom{k}{m+1} = \binom{k+1}{m+1},$$

which transforms to

$$\binom{k}{m} = \binom{k+1}{m+1} - \binom{k}{m+1}$$

to nicely telescope?

Comment: I was just about to give that. +1

Comment: Ahh of course! I get it that it is equal to (n+1 choose m+1) -(m choose m+1) which is zero. Hence it is equal to (n+1 choose m+1). Thanks!

Comment: I guess I was mistakenly given the acceptance. Tag, you're it!

Answer (score 3):

By the Binomial Theorem, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{\sum_{k=0}^n(1+x)^k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^j\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\color{#00A000}{\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{k}{j}}x^j
\end{align}
$$
By the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we also have
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{x}}
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\color{#00A000}{\binom{n+1}{j+1}}x^j
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You found an excellent replacement for the telescoping sum.